# Why does this JavaScript event not get triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically if have this that works.  It opens a query dialog box

```
$("#opener").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "hello.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#dialog").html(data).dialog("open");
        }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true
    });
});​
```

I want to call it from a

```
onClick="callMyFuncion(withDetails);
```

and basically send an ajax get request with myDetails.. heres what I'm trying

```
function getDayDetails(details) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: details,
        url: "hello.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#dialog").html(data).dialog("open");
        }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true
    });
};​
```

and calling it from here

```
<td class="everyday" onClick="getDayDetails(monthID=<?php echo $month; ?>&dayID=<?php echo $day_num; ?>&yearID=<?php echo $year; ?>);">
```

I'm new to Javascript/ Jquery.. Thanks for any help

Comment: Ugh! I suggest you use `on` with delegation, much cleaner, much more obvious.

Comment: Your original way was much better than your second way.

Comment: @elclanrs OP mentioned he is new to javascript and jquery. He probably didn't know about `on`. No need to have an attitude about it; people should feel comfortable asking questions :) That said, I totally agree that `on` is the better approach. [Relevant docs here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Lol, I was just lazy to post an answer or a "proper" comment, @vinylDeveloper, basically `on` let's you attach an event for future elements that may not exist in the DOM yet. Follow the link @banekastah shared, you'll find all info there.

Comment: I ended up using on. Thanks... also, thanks for starting your comment with ugh!. That makes me feel awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you opted to use inline JavaScript since there was no way at hand for you to make it dynamic.

An alternative could be to use `data-*` attributes to hold the date values. As shown below:

```
<td class="everyday"
    data-month="<?php echo $month; ?>"
    data-day="<?php echo $day_num; ?>"
    data-year="<?php echo $year; ?>">
  ...
</td>
```

And keep using the `.click()` function instead of inlining JavaScript [as told] which should be better avoided.

```
$("td.selector").click(function() {
  var data = $(this).data();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "hello.php",
    data: { monthID: data.month, dayID: data.day, yearID: data.year },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#dialog").html(data).dialog("open");
    }
  });
});​
```

Passing `data` to `$.ajax` as an object has the advantage that jQuery will automatically encode the parameters.

Finally, you can move the `.dialog()` initialization to a [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    modal: true
  });
});
```

Comment: I ended up using this with a jquery "on" call, compliments of the guy that chirped first for asking this question :) I mean really, why start your comment with "ugh!"?.  Thank you for your help. Everything is working sweet now.

Comment: @vinylDeveloper, if by using `.on()`, you mean instead of `.click()`. I believe `.click()` internally uses `.on()`. jQuery is full of shorthands :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now I have a focus problem. The dialog focus' on my first link putting a blue box around it. Just one issue to the next.  I guess thats how we learn. :b

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is **asynchronous** .. So it won't work this way ..

Try this

```
$(function(){ // In the DOM ready
              // define the code for the dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true
    });
});​

function getDayDetails(details) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: details,
        url: "hello.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#dialog").html(data).dialog("open");
            // Add the new HTMl to the dialog and then open..
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: re-read the code, this isn't the case -- *"So it won't work this way"*. Though i agree with moving how it is called so that he isn't re-initializing the dialog over and over

Answer (score 0):

The result paramater made by PHP is a string.
So you should wrap it in quotes too.

```
<td class="everyday" onClick="getDayDetails('monthID=<?php echo $month; ?>&dayID=<?php echo $day_num; ?>&yearID=<?php echo $year; ?>');">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it's because the `data` param isn't correct.
It should look like:

```
data: { monthID:monthValue, dayID:dayValue, yearID:yearhValue }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it, in order to avoid using all this weird onClick spaggeti code, is to encompass your parameters in the DOM by using data attributes. For example your td could become:

```
<td data-day="Mon" data-month="june">
```

So then you can grab you parameters like these:

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
     var day = $(this).attr('data-day');
     //And so on 
     //Add them to a data object 
     var data = {}; 
     data.day = day; 
     //Fire your ajax submitting the data object, 

});
```

Lastly, since ajax is asynchronous, you will have to put the dialog code inside the success callback.

Have fun.